# How can I make a read only field  form with node authors' mail address on node edit page?

Tags: entities, 6

I would like to make a read only field form on a node edit page prepopulated with the e-mail address of the node author.
I tried [Markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup) module but couldn't get it done.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Try using the [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) or the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) Module.

Comment: Thanks.I tried them but they don't seem to work for my need.

Answer (score 1):

see http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions, 
from module description:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Answer (score 0):

The [Field Readonly](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_readonly) module will help you.

> Field Readonly displays non-accessible fields in edit forms as read-only items.
>
> Modules like the essential Field Permissions allow to make fields non-accessible by completely hiding them in edit forms even if user has the permission to view them.
> Field Readonly lets you display these fields back in edit forms, rendered the same way as in view mode.